# Websocket Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED 'wss://'

Tags: jakarta-ee, https, websocket, glassfish, web.xml

I am trying to connect to the server through WebSockets only on a single page.

My client websocket:

```
var socket = new WebSocket("wss://serverName:8181/projectName/actions");
```

Java Server Endpoint:

```
/actions
```

The URL where websocket is used has this structure:

https://serverName/projectName/pageName.xhtml

My context root is same as the project name. Security constraints in web.xml file:

```
<security-constraint>  
    <web-resource-collection>  
        <web-resource-name>SecureResource</web-resource-name>  
        <url-pattern>/projectName/*</url-pattern>  
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method> 
    </web-resource-collection>  
    <user-data-constraint>  
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>  
    </user-data-constraint>  
</security-constraint>
```

I use Glassfish Application Server 4.1. The server has two http listeners. About listeners:

**Http-Listener-1:** listens port 8080, security is not enabled, websocket support is not enabled

**Http-Listener-2:** listens port 8181, security is enabled, websocket is enabled

SSL3 and TLS is Enabled in both of them. I am giving the server details because I am really a beginner about the server issues, so I dont know if these details are important. I also run the following commands while trying to find a fix. But these commands might not be related:

```
asadmin set server.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-1.http.scheme-mapping=X-Forwarded-Proto
asadmin set server.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-2.http.scheme-mapping=X-Forwarded-Proto
```

My all connections works on HTTPS without a problem. However, in the page where I use the websocket I get this error:

**WebSocket connection to 'wss://serverName:8181/projectName/actions' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**

I have tried a lot of different approach. I also tried the websocket URI without the port number. Everything had worked fine before we had a digital certificate on the server computer. I just used 'ws' instead of 'wss' back then and I didnt have the security constraints in the web.xml file. However, I am unable to provide websocket connection under HTTPS after a lot of reading and tries. Hope someone can help.

Comment: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` means the WebSocket tried to connect to an IP:Port that is either 1) not listening for connections; 2) has too many pending connections at that moment; or 3) is being blocked by a firewall/router.  There is no way for the client to know the reason why the error is happening. All it can do is move on and retry again later

Comment: So it must be either option 1 or option 3. Since it was working with ws(instead of wss), can it still be option 3? Does ws connections bypass the firewalls? BTW the server computer is connected to a university LAN.

Comment: The only thing that switching from `ws` to `wss` changes in regards to how the *underlying TCP connection* is made is the port number, nothing else changes. So, either the server isn't opening the new port for listening, or the new port is not accessible through a firewall/router between the client and server.  Either way, nothing the client can do about that on its end. This is an server administration issue, not a client programming issue

Comment: Thank you very much! I have access to the server computer. Any recommendation to make update on the server computer? Any port number changes or other settings on the glassfish application server?

Comment: Since this is now an administration issue, not a coding issue, you should ask on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) instead.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this site. Thank you very much for all the help. I will ask there.